# Impersonate SYSTEM (or equivalent) from Administrator Account

Tags: c++, windows, impersonation, privileges

This question is a follow up and continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932461) about a Privilege problem I'm dealing with currently.

**Problem Summary:**
I'm running a program under a Domain Administrator account that does not have `Debug programs (SeDebugPrivilege)` privilege, but I need it on the local machine.

**Klugey Solution:**
The program can install itself as a service on the local machine, and start the service. Said service now runs under the `SYSTEM` account, which enables us to use our `SeTCBPrivilege` privilege to create a new access token which does have `SeDebugPrivilege`. We can then use the newly created token to re-launch the initial program with the elevated rights.

I personally do not like this solution. I feel it should be possible to acquire the necessary privileges as an Administrator *without* having to make system modifications such as installing a service (even if it is only temporary).

I am hoping that there is a solution that minimizes system modifications and can preferably be done on the fly (ie: Not require restarting itself). I have unsuccessfully tried to `LogonUser` as `SYSTEM` and tried to `OpenProcessToken` on a known SYSTEM process (such as csrss.exe) (which fails, because you cannot `OpenProcess` with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` to get a handle to the process without the privileges I'm trying to acquire).

I'm just at my wit's end trying to come up with an alternative solution to this problem. I was hoping there was an easy way to grab a privileged token on the host machine and impersonate it for this program, but I haven't found a way.

If anyone knows of a way around this, or even has suggestions on things that *might* work, please let me know. I really appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: The whole point of the security policy is to set who can perform what actions.  If there were a loophole then the security policy would be worthless.  Isn't the short-term solution to have them modify their security policy?  Long-term you should separate your application out into service and user mode components.

Comment: The truth is, I have absolutely no idea why their policy is structured like this in the first place (Debug Programs is enabled by default for Administrators, so some genius intentionally removed it). Unfortunately, the policy beast is one that I am almost certainly unable to slay. In this case, however, the application really has no service portion. That is just a 'hack' of sorts that I know can be used to allow the program to relaunch itself with full debug privileges, and as clever as it may be, I don't see it as being a very clean long-term solution :(

Comment: Not sure if this thread is still active... but I might have some relevant references you might find helpful. Not sure though as some of your statements above suggest you dislike services-based 'hacks'. You may find some ideas in the article at the following link: http://www.alex-ionescu.com/recon2k6.pdf It is a little outdated, but the ideas and concepts presented in it are worth looking at to maybe give you some ideas or an approach to resolving your dilemma. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By design, no process is allowed to achieve NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM rights, unless it is started by another process with NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM rights. The service is a workaround because the Service Control Manager itself is started by the Kernel at system start.

Unfortunately, the operating system is designed to *prevent* exactly what you're trying to do. If you want to be able to remove your service afterwards, simply grant the user in question SeDebugPrivilege for the local machine and then have the service uninstall itself.

Better yet, have the program whose memory is to be modified change DACLs to allow your administrator access to it's memory without SeDebugPrivilege. Then you don't need to take privilege at all.

EDIT2: And even better yet, just use shared memory in the first place. That's what it's for.

Comment: I had predicted when writing the OP that the default answer would be "if the privilege isn't there, you're not supposed to do that". I suppose there's some truth to that, I'm just wishing that there would be a loophole through one of the Administrator's other permissions that would allow one to acquire an approved privilege token.

Unfortunately, due to the nature of this program, there is no mutual cooperation between this program and other running processes for which I need to have access. This program needs to be independent and all-mighty :(