# Is there a localization-safe way to get the SYSTEM account's AppData directory?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I know I can use `GetSystemDirectory()` to get the directory of `C:\Windows\System32`, but I'm wondering if there's a way to get this directory path below regardless of how the OS is localized or whether I'm running as a normal user or the SYSTEM account:

`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TEMP`

Or at least as far as `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData`

I tried using the `SHGFP_TYPE_DEFAULT` instead of `SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT` option for `SHGetFolderPath()` but this will return the currently running user's directory instead of SYSTEM's when not running as SYSTEM.

```
void GetUserLocalTempPath(std::wstring& input_parameter) {
    HWND folder_handle = { 0 };
    WCHAR temp_path[MAX_PATH];
    auto get_folder = SHGetFolderPath(
        folder_handle, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_DEFAULT, temp_path
    );
    if (get_folder == S_OK) {
        input_parameter = static_cast<const wchar_t*>(temp_path);
        input_parameter.append(L"\\TEMP");
        CloseHandle(folder_handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: not clear in what is problem/question. you can get file path as is

Comment: not clear what you're not clear about @RbMm. Are you saying localization doesn't matter and that it will always be in English?

Comment: but function return to you filesystem path. as is. what localization you want here ?

Comment: I don't know if this part of the path, `config\systemprofile\AppData` is ever translated, or always in English. If it's not always in English, then I need to find out how to get this part of the path, otherwise the answer to this question is, just use `GetSystemDirectory()` and append `L"\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData"` to it.

Comment: no, correct way use `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath` with `FOLDERID_LocalAppData` with localsystem token or when you run/impersonate localsystem. you not need hardcode `L"\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData"`

Comment: Okay. So could you please leave an answer then on how to do that? :)

Comment: but `SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, temp_path)` for example (if you run as *LocalSystem*) how you use `folder_handle` not correct - this is hwnd and in only parameter. the `CloseHandle(folder_handle);` of course wrong

Comment: Okay. Maybe show me this stuff in an answer?

Comment: but are you running as *LocalSystem* ? or have *LocalSystem* token ? from which context you try get this path ? are you elevated app at all ?

Comment: The question states that I need to get this path _regardless_ of the user that launches this app and I don't know anything about this token stuff you're talking about.

Comment: It doesn't appear what you're proposing is even possible :( https://stackoverflow.com/a/2992245/3543437

Comment: access system token is possible if you have debug privilege. the path is usual `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local` so question is how expand `%USERPROFILE%` for *LocalSystem*. not sure are this simply possible from not elevated user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a process running under the `SYSTEM` account in order to query the `SYSTEM` profile.

Create a separate service that runs as `SYSTEM`.  When needed, have it call [`SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath), specifying `NULL` for the user token so that it queries the calling user's (ie `SYSTEM`) profile (or, just use [`GetTempPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppathw), which [will also work in this context](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/deb60504-30a3-46b8-a45e-9a868b821304)).

Then, the service can pass that path back to your main app through any session-agnostic IPC mechanism that you want (pipes, sockets, etc).

On a side note:

- you do not need to type-cast `temp_path` when assigning it to `input_parameter`.  `temp_path` will implicitly *decay* into a `wchar_t*` pointer, which can be passed as-is to the `const wchar_t*` pointer that [`std::wstring::operator=()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) takes as input.
- rather than using `input_parameter.append(L"\\TEMP")` manually (which you would not need at all if you use `GetTempPath()`), you should consider using [`PathCchCombineEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchcombineex) (or related) or [`SHGetFolderPathAndSubDir()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathandsubdirw) instead.  Let the OS handle the appending for you.
- you are calling [`CloseHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle) with an `HWND` as input, which is wrong since it expects a `HANDLE` instead (but this is a no-op in your case since the `HWND` is NULL, so just remove the `CloseHandle()` altogether). Clearly you are not compiling your project with [STRICT Type Checking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/strict-type-checking) enabled, otherwise the compiler would have prevented an `HWND` from being passed to a `HANDLE` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `STRICT`! I'll check that out :)

Answer (score 0):

[Remy Lebeau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55718550/3543437) is the correct way to do this programmatically. However, it might be more than what's required for *you*; you might not want to jump through all those hoops if your reason for needing this doesn't require multi-generation OS support. So if you're in Windows 10-land, it *seems* safe right now to do this. That said, I don't recommend this for its fundamental short-comings. This is just an easy sloppy workaround, so **use at your own risk**.

I don't have any supporting documentation for this potential solution's longevity, just anecdotal feedback and some personal testing.

I heard from a couple people that the vital OS system directories are not localized. I installed a Windows 10 Pro Japanese image onto a Hyper-V host as a Virtual Machine. Pasting and entering the string, `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData` into the Japanese Explorer address bar worked just fine as shown below,


[image: japanese_win10_vm_sysprof_appdata]


The gist here being, after you get the value of the system directory (we can't assume `C:\WINODWS\system32`) you should be able to hard-code the rest with plain English. Here's a sample app that can accomplish that for you:

```
#define STRICT
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <memory>

int wmain()
{
    static constexpr const wchar_t * SystemProfileAppData_RemainingPath
        = L"\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData";

    wchar_t system_path_buffer[MAX_PATH];
    const std::size_t winapi_worked = GetSystemDirectory(system_path_buffer, MAX_PATH);

    if (winapi_worked) {
        const std::size_t system32_offset = wcsnlen_s(system_path_buffer, MAX_PATH);
        const std::size_t appdata_offset  = wcsnlen_s(SystemProfileAppData_RemainingPath, MAX_PATH);
        const std::size_t path_bytes_size = (appdata_offset + system32_offset) * sizeof(wchar_t);

        memcpy_s(
            &system_path_buffer[system32_offset],
            path_bytes_size,
            SystemProfileAppData_RemainingPath,
            path_bytes_size
        );

        wprintf_s(L"SYSTEM's AppData is here: %s\r\n", system_path_buffer);

        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

> `SYSTEM's AppData is here: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData`